# Moving breadcrumbs location on page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, breadcrumb

I've added breadcrumbs to my page using the method described here. I also have a top navigation bar with some jquery in place to prevent text in the topnav dropdowns from wrapping.

I'd like to move the breadcrumbs off of the topnav line and place them somewhere below the page title. My problem is that I can't figure out how to move them without breaking the topnav in some way.

[image: Current look]

[image: Desired look]